# I'm having a small issue creating a file in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program which has the user enter some names and it creates a file with these names. I'm using Python 3.2.

```
number = eval(input("How many names are there? "))
#Say the user enters 2
outfile = open('names.txt', 'w')

for i in range(number):
    name = input("Enter a name >> ")
#Say the user first enters Bob
#Then the user enters Joe

print (name, file=outfile)
outfile.close()
print ("Names have been written to file")
```

It works but there's one problem. The file that now shows up only reads one line: "Joe". None of the other names appear, only the last one.

Comment: When this program asks me to enter a number I will enter `import os; os.system("format c:")`.

Comment: @filmor means that you should avoid using `eval` as much as possible, especially when you are running it against user input.

Comment: What filmor is trying to say is that your code is very unsafe. You should be using int(input(...)) instead of eval.

Comment: What @filmor is trying to say, is don't use `input`, use `raw_input` and `int(raw_input())` because you expect ints and stings respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You have this code: -

```
for i in range(number):
    name = input("Enter a name >> ")
#Say the user first enters Bob
#Then the user enters Joe

print (name, file=outfile)
```

You print statment should be inside the loop..

```
for i in range(number):
    name = input("Enter a name >> ")
    print (name, file=outfile)
```

Comment: @Averagekid.. Thanks..but nah, I'm not.. I'm learning Python too.. But still you can accept the answer, by clicking the arrow besides the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Indentation! As your code is written now, the statement `print (name, file=outfile)` is executed once, and outside of the loop. So the last time `name` was set to anything is the one which remains.

To fix this, make sure that statement writing to the file is called right after it is input, and for that to happen, you should indent it as deep as the input statement, to be called as much times as the input is being taken.